# Java 8 installation doesn't yield the correct javac version

Tags: installation, java

I am using Mac version 10.9.5. I had a pre-existing JDK 7 installation (1.7.0_51). I decided to install try out Java 8 and downloaded the latest JDK (jdk-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg) from Oracle site.

Next, I run the install, which ended successfully.

I run the following command to see if the system registers a JDK 8 install:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Next, I check to see the version that javac prints as below:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 --exec javac -version
javac 1.7.0_51
```

Next,

```
$ ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel  99376 Sep 17 20:13 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac

$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version  
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac -version
javac 1.7.0_51
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have both versions installed

Comment: Yes, I do. But I expected 'javac' exec inside '../jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/.../bin path to print "jdk1.8.0_25", and not "jdk1.7...". I traced this issue while trying to diagnose compile time error "Error: java: invalid source release: 8".

Comment: Well the date on "Javac isn't correct since theast update was released after the file modification date.

Comment: I just uninstalled both jdk1.7 and jdk1.8 from disk. Followed http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html for removal instructions that amount to "sudo rm -rf ...". Re-installed jdk1.8 and the problem is solved. Very strange!!!

Comment: It's not really strange the version of that build wasn't even correct.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am puzzled about the date as well. However the date matches for both java and javac exec. Further, I am simply running the installer; no manual bit-copies. Thanks for your time. I am past my troubles for now.

Comment: Well u25-b32 is the right build number which isn't what -version was reporting for you